# Pandas Dataframe Categorical data transformation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having pandas dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
  
# dictionary with list object in values

# Item=[Item1, Item2, Item3]
details = {
    'Date' : ['2022-01-09', '2022-01-09', '2022-01-09', '2022-01-10', '2022-01-10'],
    'Item' : ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item1','Item2'],
    'Price' : [23, 51, 62, 31,44],
    
}
  
# creating a Dataframe object 
df = pd.DataFrame(details)
```

df

---

| Date | Item | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-09 | Item1 | 23 |
| 2022-01-09 | Item2 | 51 |
| 2022-01-09 | Item3 | 62 |
| 2022-01-10 | Item1 | 31 |
| 2022-01-10 | Item2 | 44 |

I want to transform the above pandas dataframe as follows, can anyone please help.

| Date | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Total_Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-09 | 23 | 51 | 62 | 136 |
| 2022-01-10 | 31 | 44 | NAN | 75 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new `total` column:

```
df1 = (df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Item', values='Price', aggfunc='sum')
         .assign(Total_Price = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1)))
print (df1)
Item        Item1  Item2  Item3  Total_Price
Date                                        
2022-01-09   23.0   51.0   62.0        136.0
2022-01-10   31.0   44.0    NaN         75.0
```

Comment: Can you also help to with code with which I can revert the table back tom it's original format.

Comment: @curious_ands - Use `df = df.drop('Total_Price', axis=1).melt(ignore_index=False)`